# No graphical login after purging Cinnamon

Tags: kubuntu, login-screen, xserver

I wanted to try Cinnamon and installed it: `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

But it didn't work well, because all the gnome stuff was missing on my Kubuntu. So I purged cinnamon and rebooted. Now I can't login on TTY7 (graphical interface) any more. I was stuck in a login loop...

I tried `chown`ing and deleting `.Xauthority`, but with no effect. How can I fix my graphical login? It's really annoying to login on TTy1 and then `startx`...

Comment: Please explain what your symptoms were. Was it that you couldn't log in or that no GUI appeared? I'm guessing you had a login loop from your answer but please clarify for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` I noticed that the KDE greeter still wanted to start Cinnamon, because it was set to "start previous session". I set the tick to KDE and the problem was solved.